# How to create a list of machine learning models?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, machine-learning

I am training a series of machine learning models on 30 different datasets(with same dimensions). I want to store these models in a list. All models are the same i.e. DecisionTreeRegressor() but each of them is trained on different data set.

```
model_list = []
for i in range(30):
    model = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth= None, criterion ='mse')
    model.fit(x[i], y[i])
    model_list.append(model)
```

I can use the above code but it will store all the models with the same name for each model i.e. 'model'. I want to store each of them with a different name something like ['model_1', 'model_2', 'model_3' and so on. ]

Below are  the dimensions of data x and y. For your reference. Please help.

`x.shape = 30`, `y.shape = 30`

```
x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a tuple containing the name and the model?

Answer (score 0):

```
test_model = 'x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)'
```

You can do this like below, or add name inside the `for` loop

model_df=pd.DataFrame()

```
for i in range(30):
    model_df = model_df.append([test_model])
model_df=model_df.reset_index(drop=True)
model_df['model_name'] = ['model no: ']+model_df.index.astype(str)
print(model_df)
                                               0    model_name
0   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 0
1   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 1
2   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 2
3   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 3
4   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 4
5   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 5
6   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 6
7   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 7
8   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 8
9   x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)   model no: 9
10  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 10
11  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 11
12  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 12
13  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 13
14  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 14
15  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 15
16  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 16
17  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 17
18  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 18
19  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 19
20  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 20
21  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 21
22  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 22
23  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 23
24  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 24
25  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 25
26  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 26
27  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 27
28  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 28
29  x[0].shape = (500, 5) and y[0].shape = (500)  model no: 29
```